# s3 policy/permissions for accessing old items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a bucket I am trying to give access to for a new user, new permissions or a policy are not applied to old items.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1380813163176",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1380813155817",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myuseraccess",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/myuser"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to give this iam user access to all of the s3 items easily?

Answer (score 0):

The policy you listed is an S3 bucket policy but I'm not sure why you want to give this new user access trough such a policy instead of an IAM user policy.

You can give it full access to the bucket called `mybucket` by using the following user policy in IAM:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1380883210098",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1380883292324",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1380883455145",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListBucketVersions"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    }
  ]
}
```

To attach the policy to your user, go to:

`IAM > Users > your-user > Permissions > Attach User Policy`

The `ListAllMyBuckets` permission is there to make sure the user can also access the bucket in the AWS Console and/or in apps that try to fetch the entire buckets list. You can remove it if you won't need to provide such access.